# knockout js - Updating Duplicate values together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a page, which has multiple items with editable fields. Some items on this page can be duplicates.

I want that when a user edits an item all its duplicates reflect the same edited values.

How can I implement this?

In Response to the suggsetions -

I identify them as duplicates as they have common id.

Comment: I think that you will need to add some additional details.  How do you identify that the items are duplicates?  Do they have the same values or ids?

Comment: If you are binding same value to one or more input/non-editable fields then same data gets displayed. Are you having multiple input fields? Can you post your html/js code

Comment: if you map the duplicates to the same object in your viewModel, it will work, it's the key of this problem imo

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your duplicates are represented as the same item in your view model, and/or you have a way of figuring that out in your viewModel when one of the duplicates changes.

If Duplicates aren't already a dependentObservable you could make them one and or do a subscribe on the Observable that you are checking for duplicates on and when that changes update any related duplicates.